Getting error No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test even For Hibernate6
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_product")
public class ProductEntity
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private  Integer productId;
    @Column(name="product_nm")
    private String productName;
private Integer quantity;  
private Double unitPrice;
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name="created_on")
private LocalDateTime createdOn;
@Column(name="updated_on")
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

public interface ProductDao
{
    ProductEntity saveProduct(ProductEntity product);

ProductEntity loadProductById(Integer productId);

ProductEntity updateProductById(Integer productId, Double newUnit_Price);

ProductEntity deleteProductById(Integer productId);

}
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao
{
private EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");

@Override
public ProductEntity saveProduct(ProductEntity product) {
    EntityManager entityManager=factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        entityManager.persist(product);
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("Product is inserted into database");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        System.out.println("Error in inserting product");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    return product;
}

@Override
public ProductEntity loadProductById(Integer productId) {
    EntityManager entityManager=factory.createEntityManager();
    ProductEntity p = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class,productId);
    entityManager.close();
    return p;
}

@Override
public ProductEntity updateProductById(Integer productId, Double newUnitPrice)
{
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        ProductEntity product = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class, productId);
        if (product != null) {
            product.setUnitPrice(newUnitPrice);
            entityManager.merge(product);
            tx.commit();
            return product;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Product not found for update");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        System.out.println("Error updating product");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public ProductEntity deleteProductById(Integer productId) {
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        ProductEntity product = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class, productId);
        if (product != null) {
            entityManager.remove(product);
            tx.commit();
            return product;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Product not found for deletion");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        System.out.println("Error deleting product");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return null;
}


<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.durgasoft.app01.beans.ProductEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/durgadb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />


        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductDao productDao = new ProductDaoImpl();
        // Create a product
        ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity();
        product.setProductName("Table");
        product.setQuantity(10);
        product.setUnitPrice(25.5);
        // Save the product
        productDao.saveProduct(product);
    // Load the product by ID
    ProductEntity loadedProduct = productDao.loadProductById(product.getProductId());
    System.out.println(loadedProduct);

    // Update the product
    loadedProduct.setUnitPrice(30.0);
    productDao.updateProductById(loadedProduct.getProductId(), 30.0);

    // Load the product again to verify update
    loadedProduct = productDao.loadProductById(product.getProductId());
    System.out.println(loadedProduct);

    // Delete the product
    productDao.deleteProductById(product.getProductId());

    // Try to load the deleted product (should be null)
    loadedProduct = productDao.loadProductById(product.getProductId());
    System.out.println(loadedProduct);
}

}
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.durgasoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>app01</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>app01</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>

Still getting error
jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test
at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at com.durgasoft.app01.dao.ProductDaoImpl.(ProductDaoImpl.java:8)
at com.durgasoft.app01.test.Test.main(Test.java:9)
